# Calculate the payoff of first player in mixed strategies.

Tags: game-theory

We have a game G in the form:

\begin{array}{c|ccc}
 & a & b & c \\
\hline
d & (1,1) & (0,2) & (1,3) \\
e & (3,-1) & (2,1) & (1,0) \\
f & (5,-1) & (0,0) & (3,2) \\
\end{array}

Calculate:

a) $\widetilde{u}_1\left(\frac{1}{5}a + \frac{2}{5}b + \frac{2}{5}c, \frac{2}{3}e + \frac{1}{3}f\right)$

b) $Br_1(\frac{1}{2}d + \frac{1}{2}e)$.

For subpoint b, the result is:

$Br_1(\frac{1}{2}d + \frac{1}{2}e)$ = $\{p\cdot b + (1-p)\cdot c : 0 \leq p \leq 1 \}$.

But for the subpoint a I have no idea.